# Maven container should wait for MySQL container to be ready

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command-line

**Background**

Say I have a docker-composer setup with a `maven` container, and a `mysql` container.

I can make the Maven container `depends_on: mysql`, but it doesn't wait until it's "ready". It just waits until it's running. But I have some init scripts in the MySQL container that needs to run before it's truly ready.

What I'd like to be able to do is make the Maven container wait by repeatedly trying to establish a connection to the database.

The problem with this is that the Maven container has neither `iputils`, nor `apt-get`.

**Current solution**

Maven allows you to hook into the lifecycle stages of the Java application, so you can do programmatic checks from the Java code. This is the current working solution. However, I'd prefer to be able to do this before the application starts, in a more CLI way.

**Question**

Can containers that aren't `alpine` or `ubuntu` or whatever, still get commands like `ping` and `nc` even though they don't have `apt-get`?

Alternatively, are there any other clever solutions to get the desired outcome?

Comment: There's quite a bit of discussion on this topic in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y); do the approaches there help?  Most Docker images are based on some underlying Linux distribution, most frequently Debian, so `apt-get install` is usually an option.  Sending ICMP packets doesn't really prove anything (in Docker it usually tells you the container exists but not more) and I wouldn't consider ping(1) a useful tool here.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Yes and no. That's where I got the ideas to use `depends_on` and `nc`, but as I mentioned, they don't really work in my case (as far as I know).